# What do double parallel lines on vectors mean?

Tags: vector-spaces, notation

What do the lines mean in the notation $\|u\|$ where $u$ is a vector?

Comment: It means norm (magnitude) of the vector.

Comment: Ah so length? i'm assuming i use the distance formula and the second point is 0,0

Comment: Yes, the norm of a vector is the distance from the origin 0 to the endpoint of the vector, when vectors are interpreted as points.

Comment: Ah awesome, thankyou.

Comment: The distance given by the Pythagorean formula is not the only norm, but it is likely to be what was intended if nothing further is told about the norm.  This norm is called the 2-norm and (more commonly) the Euclidean norm.

Comment: I don't see how this question is "off-topic" or needs additional context. I had been wondering what the meaning of the double-bar notation myself, since I had seen formulas that use both the double-bar and single-bar notation. This is a perfectly good question.

Answer (score 2):

That notation usually represents the Euclidean norm of a vector. If $u=\langle u_1,u_2,\dots,u_n\rangle,u_i\in\mathbb{R}$, then $||u||=\sqrt{u_1^2+u_2^2+\cdots+u_n^2}$. If $u_i\in\mathbb{C}$, then $||u||=\sqrt{u_1\bar u_1+u_2\bar u_2+\cdots+u_n\bar u_n}$.

More info on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm).

Comment: $u_1,u_2,u_3$ are scalars or vectors?

Comment: $u_1$, $u_2$, $u_3$, etc. are scalars.